AWS Cognito out of the box redirect_uri
I have a website that is completely front-end with no back-end server. I'm trying to implement OAuth2 in it through AWS Cognito and some identity providers like Google.
My question is, are there any out-of-the-box AWS Cognito features that let me exchange the authorization code I got from Google with an access token? Do you think I should implement that myself using AWS Lambda functions and API Gateways?
I got it working using a frontend page with the authorization code as a query parameter, but I don't like it this way because that code is being exposed in the browser.

The authorization code appearing in a URL is by design. Exposing it to the user should not be a security risk unless something went really wrong.

That's good to hear, less work for me then! lol
